# Geolocation country and city?

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I'm trying to to use someone's example code to get the country and city, but...something seems to be wrong. Meaning, no error, but also no alerts() pop up. It must be something really simple, but...so far I haven't managed to figure it out. See http://triparound.org/temptest.php

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ah, really weird, simple thing, `type="text/javascript"` instead of `type="javascript"` was required.